# SQL reference table with 2 ranges

Tags: sql, design-patterns, search, reference

I have a reference tables with two numeric columns which define a range, for instance employees for an account and for each employee range I get a company size :

```
employeeMin   employeeMax   Size
1             100           small
101           2000          medium
2001          10000         medium-large
10001         100000        large
```

...and so on

and I need to return Size given a parameter, say 110 would return 'medium'
as you see second column is always = first column+1

so I was wondering if it better to implement it in sql like above with two columns, or should i use only the employeeMax and maybe order and return first record? I would expect a pattern to exist? maybe self joins or similar? I did some research but couldnt find...

Comment: can you have 100 full-time and 1 half-time employee? what RDMS - MySQL 5, Oracle 11g, SQL Server 2008? what will be the most common uses - join with `accounts` table with actual number of employees? how often do you want to update these categories?

did you consider a config file you load in your program on startup instead of with each particular query?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends all on your goals, e.g.:

**maintainability** - use 1 column if you don't read it often or use any kind of optimization (e.g. materialized views)

```
employeeMax   Size
100           small
2000          medium
10000         medium-large
100000        large

select *
from accounts a
join (      
    select
        cs1.emploeeAbove,
        coalesce(min(cs2.emploeeAbove), 999999999) employeeMax,
        Size
    from company_sizes cs1
    left join company_sizes cs2
        on cs2.employeeAbove > cs1.employeeAbove
    group by cs1.employeeAbove, Size
) cs
    on a.emploees > cs.employeeAbove
    and a.employees <= cs.employeeMax
```

**faster joins** - use 2 column design if you have milions of records and you don't figure out how to optimise the previous approach

```
employeeAbove   employeeMax   Size
0               100           small
100             2000          medium
2000            10000         medium-large
10000           100000        large

select *
from accounts a
join company_sizes cs
    on a.emploees > cs.employeeAbove
    and a.employees <= cs.employeeMax
```

Comment: Nice one, although I think `0` is misplaced. A company with 0 employees is not a *small* company, it is a *non*-company.

Comment: 1) that's the meaning of "above." 2) i co-own a company that has no employees (i don't employ myself).  it's not small, it's micro, but it indeed exists.

Comment: Didn't realise a company without employees could exist *de jure*. Anyway, it was indeed your #1 that I missed: I didn't take notice of how you were actually using the lower bound. So, thanks for pointing that out for me.

Comment: @tom12345 please accept an answer if you feel your original question was answered satisfactorily ..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using only the `employeeMin` column, and remove `employeeMax`. This way, the max size is open-ended for "x-large" sizes you may have in the future.

```
 SELECT Size FROM yourtable WHERE employeeMin <= 110 ORDER BY employeeMin DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use one column, whether min or max. Among other things, this ensures that you don't have any gaps between your ranges.  Assuming max, your table would look like:

```
employeeMax   Size
100           small
2000          medium
10000         medium-large
100000        large
```

And your query to get the actual ranges would be something like:

```
select 
     coalesce((select max(employeeMax) 
               from CompanySize b 
               where b.employeemax < a.employeemax),
              0) as employeeMin
     a.employeeMax, 
     a.size
from CompanySize
```

If your database supports analytic functions, you can simplify this somewhat:

```
select 
     coalesce(lag(employeeMax) over (order by employeemax asc),
              0) as employeeMin
     a.employeeMax, 
     a.size
from CompanySize
```

Comment: please feel free to iterate all pros and cons instead "among other things" ;)

Comment: @deathApril: I'll admit that I tend to use that phrase as a hedge against the idea that there are good arguments that I haven't thought of. I'd rather leave the impression that there may be other good reasons to follow my suggestion, rather than the impression that there's only the one justification.